# What would it look like from the ground if a rogue star approached Earth?

Tags: astronomy

I imagine it would start as a new star, then get slowly bigger and brighter over the course of years. I'm wondering what color it would be, how it would affect the day/night cycle etc.

Comment: Well... first it would look like a star, then it would still look like a star until you died, and then your children died, and many more generations of people died before it would even begin to look out of place in the sky.  Stars are VERY far apart compared to how fast they move and anything close enough right now to not already be noticed as on a collision course with Earth probably not get here until after man kind is extinct.

Comment: The color of a rogue star is going to just be the color of the star (unless it's really blueshifted on approach, but then you have bigger problems). Stars come in all sorts of colors from red to yellow to white to blue, though ones on the bluer half of that spectrum are generally bigger and brighter than the Sun, which makes them liable to bake the Earth altogether as they enter the solar system.

Answer (score 5):

## A pretty normal star

you see, stars don't move that fast compared to other stars, and even travelling at light speed the closest star would take half a decade to reach earth, most stars however aren't the closest star and would take centuries moving at light speed, however your star isn't going to be moving at light speed so it would literally take thousands and thousands and thousands of years if not millions to get remotely close to earth, the only indicator that its heading to earth is that it would be heavily [blueshifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueshift) but again, your star isn't gonna be moving very fast in the first place.